# How to scan all items from a table and delete them?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to delete all items of an DynamoDB table. So I first scanned them with a function getData(), then I want to delete them one by one with the function deleteItem(), but I have no idea how to link these two function.

Do you have any idea how get all my item one by one from getDate() to delete them ? 
I did this, but I am not sure if it's correct.

```js
    function deleteItem(item){
      let deleteParam = {
        TableName : process.env.TABLE_NAME,
        Key : {
          "ASSETNAME" : item.ASSETNAME
        }
      };
      documentClient.delete(deleteParam, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
              console.error("Fail"+err);
          }
      });
    }

    function getData(){
      let scanningParameters = {
        TableName : process.env.TABLE_NAME
      };

      documentClient.scan(scanningParameters, function(err,data){
        if(err){
          callback(err, null);
        }else{
          callback(null,data);
        }
      });
```

Thanks !

Comment: Are you trying to read and process all the data, or do you just need to delete everything?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to delete all the data in your table there is a much more efficient and cheaper option:  delete and recreate the table.

Deleting many items one by one will take a long time and will cost a lot (each delete counts as 1 WCU).